# What will happen if a process run by eclipse is terminated while the process is doing IO (writing)?

Tags: eclipse

Suppose the process is writing 10k stuff to disk, and during that time terminate is issued (red button in eclipse), will the write be successful? Do I need to check integrity issues for that if I terminate it this way?

I was processing millions of documents, and I have to write one file for each document, they are small (< 10k usually). While the code is running, I found a change that could raise efficiency, so I terminated the process and made the changes. Then, I came up with this question.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect time for a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

The writing of the file will terminate with the process, leaving the file with partial content.